# OpenStreetMap following road/street latlng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openstreetmap, leaflet

I'm working on a webapp using OpenStreetMap and Leaftlet, this app will seems like an GPS app using your car position to navigate the map, In this case **I need to obtain the next 100 to 200 meteres of the driving road, to retrieve additional information about the street.**

**Any ideas ?**

E.g When car through the next 100 meters I will Suggest to take another way because there is a traffic jam there..

Thanks

Comment: Good luck and let us know how your development goes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get road name or street name from GPS coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941421/how-to-get-road-name-or-street-name-from-gps-coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways of obtaining [small snapshots of OSM data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Download#Small_amounts_of_data). But "the next 100 to 200 meteres" won't suffice under all circumstances. A detour can be way longer.